# Putting 's' in a certain context

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Should it be:

> "laboratory **tests** results" or "laboratory test results"

for doing different types of tests, not just one?

I feel the first one sounds weird, although I think it's correct grammatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire construction, 'laboratory test results' is a [Noun Phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase)

The count of 'test' isn't used, it stays singular.

> We received 1000 laboratory test results
>   We received 1 laboratory test result

Only 'result' carries the count agreement.

Answer (score 0):

You can say

*the results of laboratory tests*

to avoid the awkwardness of "tests results"